# Ubuntu very slow

Tags: 14.04

I am trying ubuntu for the first time on my computer. I have download universal USB installer to boot ubuntu without install with the try ubuntu option.

But all is very slow. I try to move files to other usb and the transfer is very very slow, I open fifefox and search on google and sometimes it stop loading and all the screen becomes black and white. Also if I try to open anything it take too much time.

Is this normal? I am doing something wrong?

EDIT: My pc is a lenovo intel core i3, 2,53GHz, 4 GB DDR3 SDRAM

Comment: Live USB is mainly there to try if everything works and to launch the installation. It is normal that it's slower than a normally installed system. On the other hand you may need to install a proprietary video driver to make things faster if you have an Nvidia or ATI video adapter.

Comment: I run Ubuntu (based Mint) live every day, especially with `toram` everything runs from ram so reads go at 2GB/second instead of HD speed 40MB/second + seek time lag, or usb/cd speeds of 2MB/second. Programs start up in 1-10 seconds(gimp slowest?), biggest delays are from network/internet. But installing video drivers is a problem when everything is lost at reboot (with no persistence)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal if the system memory is low. The entire operating system will be loaded on system memory and can be frustratingly slow if memory is full.

If you can add the system configuration that will help in giving a better answer.

Comment: That sounds more like what happens on a normal installed system, with a hard drive cache that starts thrashing ram to disk if ram gets filled up.

Comment: Yeah, but from my experience, the live disk uses considerably higher amount of memory than normal installation. Not sure exactly how this works. On my machine with 8GB ram, almost 1/3rd is used while booting a live disk (from system monitor) and less than 1GB on a normal boot.

Comment: A big part of the extra ram used is definitely from the overlayfs and tmpfs that stores every file (not on a physical disk) like $HOME and /tmp in ram. When I boot live with `toram` it uses around 1.2GB to 1.6GB just for files, plus there's the programs and regular stuff normally in ram.

Answer (score 0):

For a live (usb/cd/dvd) Ubuntu it doesn't use the hard drive, but it does read from the usb/cd when it loads programs, and that could be as slow as your usb drive.

With 4GB of ram that should be plenty to only try out a few programs, Ubuntu live uses ram to store all your files so it could get filled up if you download lots or have the web browser cache too big.

Running out of ram used to freeze older Ubuntu's, and the "real" used ram is a combination of what `free` reports plus the files in ram (from `df -t overlayfs -t devtmpfs -t tmpfs --total |tail -n 1|tr -s [:space:]|cut -d " " -f 3` in MB's for example).

But, newer Ubuntu's just semi-freeze and give errors, but you still have a chance to keep running.

If you booted it with the `toram` option (added after the "noprompt noeject" and before "--" in the boot menu, F6 should do it, more info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD_Boot_Option_Configuration_Line )  that would copy the whole iso/squashfs into ram, so loading programs from the iso would be FAST.

And, it could be that your internet connection is the slow part, network/dns settings are different or slow? Or maybe some hardware isn't 100% functional in Ubuntu, slowing down the internet, or even other hardware is slow for some reason, cpu frequency stuck on "low" or "powersave" or similar?